# Save in double variable samples of 16 bits

Tags: c++, matlab, signal-processing

I have a .pcm file which has audio data. In concrete, 17816 bytes which correspond to 8908 samples (44100 Hz and 16 bits). I want read these samples as double data, but the problem is that double is a 8 bytes.

How can I do? When I do this in Matlab with wavread function Matlab creates a double variable with 8908 samples, So I want do the same but in c++.

Comment: Converting a 16-bit integer to a `double` is pretty trivial in C++: `uin16_t i = 1337; double d = i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what MATLAB does exactly, but presumably its double values are between 0 (or -1) and 1.

In this case, you'll have to add a scaling factor (resp. denominator):

```
int16_t filevalue;
double dvalue = filevalue / 32768.;
```

or

```
uint16_t filevalue;
double dvalue = filevalue / 65536.;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read 16 bits (probably as an `unsigned short` or `uint16_t`). Then cast that value to `double`.